# How do you get Opera to not display the arrow on fields like the date input fields

Tags: html, date, opera

I was looking at this site: http://slides.html5rocks.com/#new-form-types And noticed in opera they don't show the little arrow when you customize the fields (opera reverts fields to very crappy style when you apply styles to them). Namely there's usually a down pointing arrow on the date field there.

I was wondering how to emulate the behavior. How do you tell Opera not to display that arrow, or what's the trick to it, since I've went into dragonfly and tried every single value in the original and it still shows the arrow on my test page. :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was just some sort strange bug in opera. After some time and refreshes I can't get it to not show anymore on that site. :(

Ah well...